# How can I create nested store pipes?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to achieve a use case where I have TWO stores from which I have to get values in a sequence. The goal is to ultimately call an http service with these two values pulled from the stores.

I tried creating two SEPARATE observables to get the values back individually and then pass them along to the httpClient - but am curious if should i do this or or should I attempt the following like a NESTED pipe select?

```
function userservice() {
    this.store.pipe(
    select(fromRoot.getCategories),
    take(1),
    switchMap(category => {
        this.otherstore.pipe(
        select(fromRoot.getUsers),
        take(1),
        switchMap(user => {
           return httpClient.get( apistuff with params user and category)
        })
    })
}
```

Am wondering if this is the correct approach or should I look up the two variables `user` and `category` as distincy selects() and then call httpclient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, your code is fine but it is better to avoid nesting because it leads to the situation which promises have - callback hell. If you avoid nesting then it makes your code more readable/understandable easily.

If your inner observable depends on outer observable then it is needed to do nesting otherwise you can simply compose those observable to emit the combined value in your observable pipeline.

In your example -

**If your categories and users are independent then you should do the following to avoid nesting -**

```
 function userservice() {

  return combineLatest( //or you can use zip operator as per your requirement
    this.store.pipe(
      select(fromRoot.getCategories),
      take(1)),
    this.otherstore.pipe(
        select(fromRoot.getUsers),
        take(1))
  ).pipe(
    switchMap(([categories, users]) => {
        return httpClient.get( apistuff with params user and category);
    })
  );
```

**If users depend on categories then you can do the following [this example is just to show the required nesting; not related to your scenario] -**

```
function userservice() {

  return this.store.pipe(
    select(fromRoot.getCategories),
    take(1),
    switchMap(categories => {
      return this.httpClient.get(/*get users for categories*/)
                 .pipe(
                   switchMap(users => this.httpClient.get( //apistuff with params user and category))
                 );
    })
  )  
}
```

You can avoid nesting in the above code by changing the code as shown below -

```
function userservice() {

  return this.store.pipe(
    select(fromRoot.getCategories),
    take(1),
    switchMap(categories => {
      return zip(this.httpClient.get(/*get users for categories*/), of(categories)); //you can use combineLatest as well as per your need
    }),
    switchMap(([users, categories]) => {
      return httpClient.get( apistuff with params user and category);
    })
  )  
}
```

Comment: Lovely! the combineMap() sounds like exactly what I need here.

Comment: @DorianMcAllister If it answered you question, I would request to mark it as answered so that it will be helpful for the similar questions for someone. Thanks!